# Laravel Validation causes form to throw MethodNotAllowed error?

Tags: php, laravel, validation, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm pretty new to Laravel. I'm trying to create a form to post to a function in my controller. It works fine, exactly as expected, until I try to add in a custom request validation. As soon as I've added it, if I run the form again I get a MethodNotAllowed error. Can someone tell me what is going wrong?

edit** sorry I forgot to post the code.

The request I made is pretty simple. The authorize is set to return true.

```
/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
  return [
    'campaign_name'=>'required',
    'campaign_message'=>'required_without:campaign_link',
  ];
}
```

In the controller I'm calling the namespace for the request at the top and have the function using that request. The function works just fine when the regular laravel request is called rather than my custom one.

```
public function store(CreateCampaignRequest $request)
{

//do code here

}
```

My form is using this action to send the request.

```
{!! Form::open(['method'=>'POST', 
'action'=>'OrganizationCampaignController@store'])!!}
```

and the route is set to this

```
Route::post('dashboard/campaigns/send','OrganizationCampaignController@store');
```

Like I said everything works when the normal Request is called, it only throws the method not allowed when I try using my custom request.

Thank you!

Comment: *"Can someone tell me what is going wrong"* Not without posting your code... But, I'd guess your validation redirect (using `$this->validate()` in your Controller) is going to somewhere you don't have a `GET` route defined.

Comment: @TimLewis I added the code, have you had a chance to take a look at it again?

Comment: I have, but I'm not familiar with the way you're performing validation, so I don't know if I'll be able to help. Consider adding a `laravel` tag (in addition or instead of `laravel-5.2`) to increase your question's visibility.

Comment: @TimLewis thank you for getting back to me. I don't mean to keep bugging you, but I did try to use the $this->validate() in my controller and I had the same error, I also tried $request->validate(), right out of the laravel documentation and still it give me a MethodNotAllowed error. Any thoughts or do you know were I might find answers? Thanks.

Comment: That's fine. What route are you posting from, what route are you posting too, and what's the route that's throwing the `MethodNotAllowed` error? (Copy from your address bar if you can, or from the `action` value of your `POST` form)

Comment: All of the routes I'm using are the ones listed up in my original question. I'm getting an error when I'm trying to submit the form. I only get the error when I try to validate, it works perfectly without validation. This is the error I get                                       
      protected function methodNotAllowed(array $others)
    {
        throw new MethodNotAllowedHttpException($others);
    }

Comment: The only route you have in your question is the `POST` one, which is a third of my comment; I asked you to post the other two from your address bar; the page you're on before you submit your form, and the page you're on when you get the `MethodNotAllowed` error.